# How to generate model from a user uploaded file?

Tags: r, shiny, linear-regression

I have created a file upload section that uploads and reads CSV files as a table:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

titlePanel("Upload Transaction Data Set"),

 sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

  fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
            multiple = FALSE,
            accept = c("text/csv",
                     "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                     ".csv")),
  tags$hr(),

  checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

  radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
               choices = c(Tab = "\t"),
               selected = "\t"),

  radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
               choices = c(None = "",
                           "Double Quote" = '"',
                           "Single Quote" = "'"),
               selected = '"'),

  tags$hr(),

   radioButtons("disp", "Display",
               choices = c(Head = "head",
                           All = "all"),
               selected = "head")

),

mainPanel(

  tableOutput("contents")
       )
)
```

I have also created linear regression models that takes input from a data set:

```
thedata <- readxl::read_xlsx("data/transactionDataAlteredXLSX.xlsx")

set.seed(2)
library(caTools)
split <- sample.split(thedata, SplitRatio=0.7)

train <- subset(thedata, split=TRUE)
Actual <- subset(thedata, split=FALSE)


# Create the model
Model <- lm(Class ~.,data=train)
#Prediction
Prediction <- predict(Model, Actual)

#Comparing predicted vs actual model
plot(Actual$Class,type = "l",lty= 1.8,col = "red")
lines(Prediction, type = "l", col = "blue")
plot(Prediction,type = "l",lty= 1.8,col = "blue")
#Finding Accuracy

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How do I make the linear regression models form the output of the file upload, and not from the dataset 'thedata'?

Thanks.

Edit:

Converted the file to data frame as suggested in server code, I then changed "thedata" to "df" on the regression code, but now I receive the error "unique() applies only to vectors data frame", Any ideas?:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

output$contents <- renderTable({

req(input$file1)

df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
         header = input$header,
         sep = input$sep,
         quote = input$quote)

if(input$disp == "head") {
  return(head(df))
}
else {
  return(df)
}

})

}
```

Comment: I have a hunch that  I need to convert the CSV file into a data frame and use it as a variable for the model to read.

Comment: Yep, it sounds like you are on the right track. Try it out. Accept the csv input from the user, convert it into a data frame (on the server side code), check if it is in an acceptable format then perform the regression and display the results.

Comment: I've made changes, any thoughts? @Sada93

Comment: is the regression code in the server function?

Comment: Yes, is that why the models are not displaying? @Sada93

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of the code you have attached. The file I chose is the standard mtcars dataset. You can save this to your computer by calling this function:

```
write.csv(mtcars,file = "~/Desktop/Data.csv",row.names = FALSE)
```

What I do here is read in the full training dataset, perform a simple linear regression, and output the predicted dataframe against a sample test dataset (i hard coded this for now).

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Upload Transaction Data Set"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv"))

    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("prediction")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input,output){
  df = reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    read.csv(file = input$file1$datapath)
  })

  #Perform Regression
  output$prediction = renderTable({
    req(df())
    model = lm(mpg ~ disp+hp,data = df())

    sample_df = data.frame(disp = c(100,200),hp = c(100,200))
    prediction = predict(model,sample_data)

    predict_df = data.frame(mpg = prediction)
    output_df = cbind(sample_df,predict_df)
    return(output_df)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Hey this is much better, thanks! However, the only thing being returned is the selected columns from the data, and not the actual regression model, do you know why that is? @Sada93

Comment: I am not sure if it is supposed to be a table output in the mainPanel?

Comment: Think of this code as scaffolding to help you. You may replace the output with a text output or you may format the table to output the model coefficients.